# Ruby: Create A Gzipped Tar Archive

Tags: ruby, gzip, tar

What's the best way to create a gzipped tar archive with Ruby?

I have a Rails app that needs to create a compressed archive in response to user actions. Ideally, it would be possible to write directly to a compressed file without needing to generate intermediate temp files first. The [Ruby Zlib](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/classes/Zlib.html) library appears to support direct gzip compression. How can I combine this with tar output?

A number of quasi-solutions appear to have been proposed and a lot of information appears to be out of date.

For example, the top Google search result for "ruby tar" gives [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/ruby-taring-or-ziping-with-ruby-script-520696/), which was started in 2007 with apparently no resolution.

Another high-ranking search result is [this one describing ruby tar](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/32588). It dates back to 2002, and the announcement doesn't exactly inspire confidence.

I've also seen various reports of shelling out to unix tar and the like.

So, I know there are a lot of ways to do this, but I'm really looking for a recommendation to the most reliable and convenient one from someone who has tried a few of the alternatives.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is very similar to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856491/ruby-streaming-tar-gz
Anyone find an answer?

Comment: I'm still playing around with this, but this looked like a good idea. Ruby's [Archive::Tar](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/a/archive-tar-0.9.0/Archive/Tar.html)

Comment: Landed here from page one of search for `create a gzipped tar`. Please consider generalizing question for non-Ruby usage.

Answer (score 12):

If you're running under unix, you could write the files out to disk, then run a system call to tar/gzip them.

```
`tar -czf #{file_name}.tar.gz #{file_name}`
```

Comment: I like this - very easy. Even though it doesn't check that "tar" is installed on your system, it's a reasonable assumption if they've got ruby :) Don't forget the backticks "`" around it. SO wouldn't let me add spaces in front so they're visible.

Answer (score 6):

This [Ruby Minitar](https://rubygems.org/gems/minitar/) project was updated in 2009 and seems like it would solve your problem

Comment: Minitar doesn't seem to allow writing tars from a stream, only from files. It can output to a stream, though.

Answer (score 6):

The following example shows how to combine the GzipWriter class from Ruby Zlib and the TarWriter class from RubyGems to create a gzipped tar archive:

```
require 'rubygems/package'

filenames_and_contents = {
  "filename" => "content",
}

File.open("archive.tar.gz", "wb") do |file|
  Zlib::GzipWriter.wrap(file) do |gzip|
    Gem::Package::TarWriter.new(gzip) do |tar|
      filenames_and_contents.each_pair do |filename, content|
        tar.add_file_simple(filename, 0644, content.length) do |io|
          io.write(content)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```