# Ruby streaming tar/gz

Tags: ruby, stream, tar, gzip

Basically I want to stream data from memory into a tar/gz format (possibly multiple files into the tar, but it should NEVER TOUCH THE HARDDRIVE, only streaming!), then stream them somewhere else (an HTTP request body in my case).

Anyone know of an existing library that can do this? Is there something in Rails?

[libarchive-ruby](http://rubydoc.info/gems/libarchive-ruby/0.0.3/frames) is only a C wrapper and seems like it would be very platform-dependent (the docs want you to compile as an installation step?!).

SOLUTION:

```
require 'zlib'
require 'rubygems/package'

tar = StringIO.new

Gem::Package::TarWriter.new(tar) { |writer|
  writer.add_file("a_file.txt", 0644) { |f| 
    (1..1000).each { |i| 
      f.write("some text\n")
    }
  }
  writer.add_file("another_file.txt", 0644) { |f| 
    f.write("some more text\n")
  }
}
tar.seek(0)

gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(File.new('this_is_a_tar_gz.tar.gz', 'wb'))  # Make sure you use 'wb' for binary write!
gz.write(tar.read)
tar.close
gz.close
```

That's it! You can swap out the File in the GzipWriter with any IO to keep it streaming. Cookies for dw11wtq!

Comment: I should also point out that this is really memory intensive - it will fill up the StringIO with the entire tar before going to the gzip stream. A better solution for large files would be to create a buffer between the streams. I'll add code for this when I get around to implementing it...

Comment: Also note that gz.close will also close the output IO (File in this case). To keep it open, use gz.finish

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the TarWriter class in rubygems: http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Package/TarWriter.html it just operates on an IO stream, which may be a StringIO.

```
tar = StringIO.new

Gem::Package::TarWriter.new(tar) do |writer|
  writer.add_file("hello_world.txt", 0644) { |f| f.write("Hello world!\n") }
end

tar.seek(0)

p tar.read #=> mostly padding, but a tar nonetheless
```

It also provides methods to add directories if you need a directory layout in the tarball.

For reference, you could achieve the gzipping with `IO.popen`, just piping the data in/out of the system process:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/IO.html#method-c-popen

The gzipping itself would look something like this:

```
gzippped_data = IO.popen("gzip", "w+") do |gzip|
  gzip.puts "Hello world!"
  gzip.close_write
  gzip.read
end
# => "\u001F\x8B\b\u0000\xFD\u001D\xA2N\u0000\u0003\xF3H\xCD\xC9\xC9W(\xCF/\xCAIQ\xE4\u0002\u0000A䩲\r\u0000\u0000\u0000"
```

Comment: Is it possible to both write into the tar/gz functions AND read the output BOTH from IO streams? I don't want to touch the hard disk, so no files allowed!

Comment: Also, it needs to be platform-indepent, and I would rather not rely on system calls. The tools I use need to be libraries I can package myself, like gems or rb files. This is why I've wandered away from libarchive-ruby.

Comment: Looking again, this may work. I believe zlib'z Zlib::GzipWriter can use streams for both input and output, and TarWriter can as well using StringIO, as you mentioned. I will try it and give you cookies if it works.

Comment: Yeah, just use TarWriter to fill a StringIO with the tar data, then use GzipWriter to gzip that StringIO. StringIO is your friend :)

Comment: I wonder what is the performance of StringIO? What if I have a huuuuuge amount of data to stream? (I do...)

Comment: Theoretically the same as reading to/from disk (I/O is always converted to Strings anyway).  It's memory usage that will hurt you.  There's no way around that, far from writing to disk... which begs the question, why are you so opposed to writing to disk, if you have to work with large amounts of data?  File streaming is *the* exact pattern to avoid high memory usage.

Comment: Does this work on binary data? I would think things get messed up when you use StringIO to convert everything to strings

Comment: In ruby Strings are used to contain binary data.  In short, yes, it will work.

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out how to copy binary data from the StringIO to the GzipWriter. I think I've tried every combination of #write, #read_bytes, yada yada.

Comment: Is it producing a file with size of zero bytes?  Have you made sure to call `seek(0)` on the stream before reading it back out?

Comment: It makes a file this_is_a_tar_gz.tar.gz (from the code I posted in the question). It's the size of the data I wrote, NOT compressed. I wrote 150kb of dummy data to the StringIO when making one of the two tar files, and the resulting tar.gz is the same size. It produces a tar.gz that an archive program (like IZArc or 7Zip) can open, but it's apparently empty. Extracting the tar.gz creates a new .tar of size 0 bytes.

Comment: Got it! - needed to use 'wb' write mode for the GzipWriter's File. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution OP wrote, I wrote fully on-memory tgz archive function what I want to use to POST to web server.

```
  # Create tar gz archive file from files, on the memory.
  # Parameters:
  #   files: Array of hash with key "filename" and "body"
  #     Ex: [{"filename": "foo.txt", "body": "This is foo.txt"},...]
  #
  # Return:: tar_gz archived image as string
  def create_tgz_archive_from_files(files)
    tar = StringIO.new
    Gem::Package::TarWriter.new(tar){ |tar_writer|
      files.each{|file|
        tar_writer.add_file(file['filename'], 0644){|f|
          f.write(file['body'])
        }
      }
    }
    tar.rewind

    gz = StringIO.new('', 'r+b')
    gz.set_encoding("BINARY")
    gz_writer = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(gz)
    gz_writer.write(tar.read)
    tar.close
    gz_writer.finish
    gz.rewind
    tar_gz_buf = gz.read
    return tar_gz_buf
  end
```