# Creating a tgz file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, unix, ubuntu, zip

I've created a directory with some sub directories and in those nice little sub directories are some files.

I'd like to take that robust root directory and zip it up nicely into a .tgz file.

The code I have is `tar cvzf('/Users/me/Desktop/things.tgz', '/Users/me/Desktop/')`

Googling for the error `undefined method ‘cvzf’ for main:Object` hasn't yielded anything

Comment: How is this related to Ruby? Also, can you be a bit more specific about what "isn't working". Are you getting any error messages or ...? (I'm not downvoting .. just looking for more information)

Comment: It's related to Ruby because I'm writing this script in Ruby. Maybe it doesn't relate to Ruby. I don't know. Updating the question with errors and code.

Comment: @levon I'm new to this, I appreciate your patience here.

Comment: no problem, the way you had it before, it just looked like a question about an interactive unix tar command .. it's all good. My Ruby is a bit rusty, but you may want to include your Ruby code (just the relevant bits) for the local Ruby experts.

Comment: @levon Would you mind upvoting the question please?

Comment: I would if I had downvoted it (I didn't). I still think the question could benefit from some additional information in order for others to help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11245/discussion-between-zack-shapiro-and-levon)

Comment: Perhaps you should read a Ruby tutorial? Ruby ≠ shell scripting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: Create A Gzipped Tar Archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113087/ruby-create-a-gzipped-tar-archive)

Comment: Also see: "[Library to read/write TAR files](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/89933).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error correctly described your problem: you're calling a method called `cvzf` with the two file paths as arguments, however there is no such method in Ruby. (Ruby also doesn't know what `tar` is, but the other error happens to be caught first)

If all you want to do is call a shell command from within a Ruby script, just enclose the command in backquotes like this:

```
`tar cvzf "/Users/me/Desktop/things.tgz" "/Users/me/Desktop"`
```

However that will only work if your system has the tar program. Otherwise you could try installing some [Ruby gems](http://rubygems.org/search?query=tar) that add tar capabilities to Ruby.